# Load image to ImageView in vertical position wtihout superimpose on icons in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to ask about what I should to do if I want to limit place of ImageView in Android? When picture was load in horizontal position, it is ok, but when I load image in vertical position, photo superimposed on the icons.
My code of ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/sample" />
```

How can I to repair it?

Answer (score 1):

As you set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `wrap_content`, the source image may extend beyond what is expected so it gets fit correctly.

You could set a defined dimension for the image when in portrait (in the values-port folder) or even a different layout for portrait and landscape using the layout-land and layout-port folders.

Also, have you tried different values for `android:scaleType`? You can check more about them in this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)